# JavaFx node snapshot is scaled down when node is stretched to fit parent size

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, javafx-8

I've implemented a small example that shows the problem.
I have a node that fits the width of its parent. When I start a drag & drop gesture on that node, I create a snapshot of the node and I set it as the image of the drag view.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    HBox root = new HBox(10);

    Label someText = new Label("some text");
    someText.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
    someText.setPrefHeight(50);
    root.getChildren().add(someText);

    root.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
        Dragboard db = root.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.put(DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, "test");
        db.setContent(content);

        WritableImage image = root.snapshot(null, null);
        db.setDragView(image);

        event.consume();
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    root.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());

    stage.setTitle("JavaFX snapshot example");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

When I gently increase the size of the scene (with the mouse), and I start the drag & drop gesture, the drag view image has the same size of the node. But if I continue to increase the size of the scene, and I start the drag & drop gesture, at some point the drag view image gets smaller. If I maximize the scene to fit the screen size, the drag view image is tiny.

The question is why. Is it a bug? What can be done to fix or workaround this issue?

Please note that when I add some traces, I can see that image.getWidth() is the same as root.getWidth(), which is clearly weird to me.

**Edit:** reproduced on Java 8 + macOS 10.12.5, Retina screen

**Edit 2:** not reproduced on Java 8 + Windows 10 platform.

Therefore it's either a bug on the MacOS platform, or some limitation, for instance on the maximum size a drag view image can have.

Any information about the root cause would be welcome of course.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this.  On what operating system are you seeing this behavior?  What version of Java?

Comment: Same here. I could not reproduce this problem.

Comment: I can reproduce on Java 8 +  macOs 10.12.5.